# Is there an utility that tells whether a file path is a network share or on a local hard disk?

Tags: mount, path, remote, shared-folders

I want to test whether some paths are mapped onto remote shares before creating them, as they need to be created before their files are written two. They are `sshfs` paths for the time being.

A basic idea would be to check `/etc/mtab` and look for share a whose path is a long enough prefix for the path I'm testing, but I'm hoping that there is something which is more robust than something I will whip up at short notice.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/how-to-determine-what-filesystem-a-directory-exists-on) help?

Comment: @dirkt Not quite. It is not to check if the directory exists. It is to check if it would be on the remote share if it was created

Comment: Then check the prefix of that path that **does** exist in the above way, because that prefix determines on which filesystem (or "remote share") it would be created. Unless you have some weird automount setup going on where non-existing paths will get automounted as soon as they are created. But in that case you need to check the automount configuration, anyhow.